# Почему не возникает ошибки при обращении к несуществующему атрибуту обьекта?

Tags: python

Просьба не пинать, так как только недавно начал изучать ООП. Суть кода, при вызове класса Class, мы задаем атрибут для объекта kek, далее мы инициализируем объект с другим названием и задаем не атрибут этого же объекта а объекта kek, а вывести просим значение атрибута объекта который только что создали, то есть атрибута для объекта которого только инициализировали нету и должна вылезти ошибка. Обьясните почему все работает?)

```
class Class:
    def __init__(kek, a):
        kek.a = a
        print(kek.a)

    def jj(self):
        print(self.a)


stop = ''
while stop != 'stop':

    name = input('Object: ')
    number = int(input('Number: '))
    name = Class(number)
    name.jj()

    stop = input('Stop? ')
```

Comment: Вы путаете понятия *class* с понятием *instance*. И так по python замечание, лучше наследоваться от `object` и не плодить осиротевших базовых классов.

Comment: А от куда здесь должна взяться ошибка ? Ваш класс принимает один аргумент, вы его успешно передаете, ошибки здесь не какой быть не должно. Вы наверное думаете что ваш класс принимает 2 аргумента, но это не так, потому что все методы в классе по умолчанию первым аргументом принимают ссылку на экземпляр объекта класса, этого можно избежать сделав метод статическим, или методом класса, но в последнем случае метод будет принимать первым аргументом вместо объекта сам класс.

Comment: name.jj() но тут же я не kek использую а обьект который только что создал с именем name, а для него name.a нету так как при инициализации класса мы задали a только для kek

Comment: метод `jj` обращается к атрибуту `a` и принтует его, вы этот самый атрибут `a` передаете при инициализации объекта переменной `number`, а ваш `kek` это и есть созданный объект `name`

Answer (score 1):

В тех методах, которые должны получать первым аргументом self, абсолютно всё равно, как вы его назовёте, питон всё равно будет понимать под этим именем **любой** экземпляр данного класса, для которого сработал этот метод.

То есть в вашем `__init__` вы как бы говорите интерпретатору: "Сейчас я тебя научу, что ты должен делать с **каждым** новым экземпляром класса сразу после его создания, для ясности в рамках этого метода я буду называть этот каждый новый экземпляр `kek`".

И интерпретатор понимает, что до конца этого метода слово `kek`, обозначает **каждый** новый экземпляр класса.

Потом в методе `jj` вы говорите интерпретатору: "Сейчас я научу тебя, что тебе делать с **каждым** экземпляром класса, когда для него будет вызван метод jj. Для ясности я буду называть этот каждый экземпляр `self`".

И интерпретатор до конца метода запоминает, что `self` - это **каждый** экземпляр, для которого был вызван метод `jj`.

То есть первым аргументом вы можете написать любое имя, и до конца метода это имя будет обозначать **любой** экземпляр, для которого данный метод сработал. А использование именно слова `self` для этой цели - просто традиция, которую лучше всё-таки соблюдать, чтобы другим программистам было проще читать ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

Первым параметром в Init передается self, так что это тот же объект, для которого вызывается, то есть kek и есть создающийся объект.

Comment: То есть хотя и не называется self, все равно это он и есть.

Comment: ..name.jj().. в данном случае я же обращаюсь к обьекту который ввел через input, почему при вызове в self передается не ..name.. а kek?

Comment: Исходя из моего кода независимо от кого какой name я дам экземпляру класса создастся kek, это я понял, а далее когда я обращаюсь не к kek методом jj, почему получаю то что принадлежит kek?

Comment: @Andrew, а как вы проверяете объект `kek`?

Comment: через Input ввели не объект, а число. Объект создается строчкой     name = Class(number), и тут вызывается init объекта, который внутри Init называется kek

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут `a` существует, вы его в `__init__` создали (как и положено).

Методам в Питоне в качестве первого аргумента передаётся сам объект. Упрощая, `объект.метод(аргумент)` вызов это `Класс.метод(объект, аргумент)`. По соглашению, первый параметр обычно `self` называется, но технически можно любое имя использовать:

```
class Класс:
    def метод(сам_объект, параметр):
        pass
```

`объект.метод(аргумент)` вызов приводит к:

```
сам_объект = объект
параметр = аргумент
```

внутри `метод`.

Чтобы не вводить в заблуждение будущих читателей вашего кода, следует `self` имя использовать:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self,  arg):
        self.attr = arg
    def method(self):
        return self.attr**3

result = Class(2).method()
```

---

В сторону: избегайте создание классов с  единственным методом, который однократно вызывается. Лучше обычную функцию создать:

```
def cube(n):
    return n**3

result = cube(2)
```

Comment: Во первых передается не объект, а экземпляр объекта класса, не нужно путать людей неверными терминами, во вторых есть много классов с единственным методом которые используют например в виде декораторов, самый яркий тому пример небезизвестный singleton, и нет такого соглашения, что именно везде нужно первый аргумент называть self, так как в том же мета программировании, они называются по другому.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч: чушь какую-то мелете. Даже отвечать не буду. Из мести не хорошо минусы ставить.  Если этот комментарий читает будущий посетитель из гугла и не очевидно, почему чушью является предыдущий комментарий, то спрашивайте.

Comment: Если вы под видом полезной информации пишите ерунду то считаю нужным донести это до людей, а про какую вы месть говорите понятия не имею, бегаете за мной по всему форуму и пытаетесь везде свои 5 копеек вставить. Лечите нервы.

Comment: и кстати после нашего с вами спора, у меня начали волшебным образом появляться минусы, совпадение ? так что если кто то и делает  что то из за мести то это не я. Нервные клетки не восстанавливаются, будьте счастливы.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч: зачем вы лжёте? вы понимаете, что вашу ложь легко проверить? История голосований доступна.

Comment: Ваше ко мне отношение явно предвзято, иначе не могу объяснить минусование последнего моего ответа.